# writing and formatting datetime.date objects using xlwt

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm having some trouble with this bit of code

```
#data_list = some data
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
s = wb.add_sheet("Test Sheet")
for c, data in enumerate(data_list):
        xf=None
        if isinstance(data, datetime.time):
                xf = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='HH:MM:SS') #works
        elif isinstance(data, datetime.date):
                xf = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='MM/DD/YYYY') #doesn't work
        if xf:
                sheet.write(r+1,c,data, xf)
        else:
                sheet.write(r+1,c,data)
```

In the output, the dates all appear as "#####" initially. I can get excel to format them properly by interacting with a cell in each column, but it's time consuming. I'm tried playing with the num_format_str a little, but no luck so far.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just because your columns in Excel are too narrow?  If the column is to narrow to display the entire date, it will show up as "#######".

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but: Calling xlwt.easyxf is in general not cheap. Do it before entering your loop wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks to both. Terry was, of course, absolutely correct. And I discovered the mistake of calling easyxf inside the loop later too: looks like there isn't any checking to see if the xf objects are functionally the same, so I was getting an exception when trying to generate more than a certain number of them.

Comment: Checking that xf objects are functionally the same is also expensive, which is why it is disabled by default. See the `style_compression` arg of the `Workbook` constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just thinking about this some more, if your problem **is** that the columns are too narrow, you can fix it by setting the column width explicitly in your script.

```
for c, data in enumerate(data_list):
    xf=None
    sheet.col(c).width = len(str(data))*256 
    if isinstance(data, datetime.time):
```

The width in xlwt is set in units of 1/256 the width of the `0` character in the default font.